# DElphi - Indy SMTP - BUG?

Tags: delphi, email, smtp, indy

Im using Delphi and Indy V10-5218.  When sending email to our Exchange Server, I sometimes receive an Indy Internal Error Message...

```
<62d491c3-735f-4369-860c-7eaa15ece07a@BJPHSSERVER.bjphomesupport.local> [InternalId=78] Queued mail for delivery
```

Is this a bug???

Below is some sample code....

```
try
   try
     SMTP.Connect;

     if SMTP.Connected then
     begin
       try
          SMTP.Send(MailMessage);
       except
          ShowMessage('Trap Send');
       end;
     end;
  finally
     try
        if SMTP.Connected then SMTP.Disconnect;
     except
        ShowMessage('Trap Disconnect');
  end;
  end;
except
   MessageDlg('Error connecting to Email Server.'#13+
             'Please tell Lee.',mterror,[mbOK],0);
end;
```

Please note, the error message only appears randomly!!!

Many thanks

Lee

Comment: This could be a host of things. The first thing I would do was to turn logging on smtp server on, then check the logs for how many connections are in use when you code fails to connect.  You may be at max connections.

Comment: Where are you seeing that internal error message?  Your code is not displaying such an error message.  Are you seeing it as an exception when running in the debugger? Please provide more details.  Also, you should get rid of all the `Connected` calls. Let Indy raise an exception if the connection is lost unexpectedly.

Comment: Regarding logging, you can also log the SMTP traffic on the client side, and look for erroneous/unexpected replies from the server.  Use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, or connect one of the `TIdLog...` components to `TIdSMTP`.

Comment: You are catching an exception, but doing nothing with it. At least change `ShowMessage('Trap Send')` to `On E:Exception do ShowMessage('Trap Send: ' + E.Message);`